# dplr: unnest a matrix column

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, unnest

I am trying to understand `invoke_map`.  In this case I simulate
30 bivariate random normal observations and assign them to a grouping field
for later use simulating a random intercept and slope.

Everything is straight forward until I have to unnest the matrix column.

The main thing is that the `mutate(u1,u2)` line seems more complicated than
it needs to be.  What should I do instead?

```
library(dplyr)
library(mvtnorm)
N <- 30
# Simulate two correlated random normal variables into a tibble
var_u1    <-  0.0005
var_u2    <-  0.010
cov_u1_u2 <- -0.0002

SIGMA <-  matrix(c(var_u1, cov_u1_u2, cov_u1_u2, var_u2), nrow = 2) 
sim_u <- dplyr::tribble(
  ~f, ~params,
  'rmvnorm', list(n = N, mean = c(0,0), sigma = SIGMA)  
)
u <- sim_u %>% 
  mutate(u = purrr::invoke_map(f,params))   %>% 
  mutate(u0 =  purrr::map(u,`[`,i=,j=1),
         u1 =  purrr::map(u,`[`,i=,j=2))     %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(u0,u1) %>% 
  mutate(lab = 1:N) %>% 
  select(lab,u0,u1)
u
```

Comment: It comes down to adding a matrix to a tibble.

Comment: If I have nested matrix's instead of nested tables, how to I unnest them into the data frame?

Comment: I have edited it, I assume that you are using 
`library(splus2R)`. If not, what are you using? The base code wouldn't run for me.

Comment: I am not using splus2R.  I am using the dplyr, which is where the mutate function exists.

Comment: I get this error when I copy and run your code - `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: could not find function "rmvnorm".` so is there another package that you are using that has `rmvnorm`?

Comment: I added the library names.